# Background-Image as link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the background image I have in CSS turn into a link which I can reference.
I have the following in CSS:

```
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
padding: 66px;
}


#ad_11 {
background-image: url(images/index1.png);
display: block;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
padding-top:475px;
padding-bottom:0px;
margin: 20px; 
width: 519px; 
float: left;
}

#ad_12 {
background-image: url(images/index2.png);
display: block;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
padding-top:475px;
padding-bottom:0px;
margin: 20px; 
width: 510px; 
float: left;
}
```

Then, I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="ad_11"></div>
<div id="ad_12"></div>
<br style="clear: both;" /> 
</div>
```

The question is how do I turn this background image into a link. Is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by: "turn into a link which I can reference"? Do you just want the user to be able to click on the div and be taken to another page like an anchor tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible to make background images into links.

As a rule of thumb I'd say that if you need an image to be a link, then the image is content, and should be added using the `img` tag.

If the image is being used to replace some text then one thing you can do is put the background image on the anchor and style it so it's the size you want and hide the text using `text-indent`.

Here's a quick sample of how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/tS27T/

```
a{
    background: url('image_url.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To answer what I think your new question is i've put together this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nChaH/

Comment: Hi Jamie.. Please see my edited code.. I have add to allign two images.. and now I want these background images linkable. I have tried to use: <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Some Text</a></div> but that does not seem to work. An ideas? Sorry, I am new to CSS and HTML!

Comment: OK. Ive solved it! The trick is actually on:http://webdevnews.net/2007/01/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Comment: James, the link you've provided is exactly what I've said to do. The only difference is that they're hiding the text by putting it in a span. I think it's much nicer to do it with text-indent since you don't need the extra markup they're using.

Comment: I agree Jamie! your solution is more elegant! Thanks again! Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this is not possible, however, see this link for a workaround:
http://xavisys.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/